# IPMSG problem in windows 7?

Tags: windows, ipmsg

I have always used IPMSG for chatting across the LAN.  It has been working well under Windows XP, but after I installed Windows 7 it has stopped working.

When I am connected to the internet I cannot see anyone else on the local network.  As soon as I disconnect the internet I can see everyone on the local network perfectly fine.

I am using the latest version of IPMSG.
Is their any problem with IPV6 service in windows 7. Which is causing this problem.

Does anyone have any ideas or knowledge of this problem?
This is the link of this software http://ipmsg.org/index.html.en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. The new release of ipmsg is compatible with win7.
The old release of ipmsg in not compatible with win7,it doesn't detect lan ip address.

*http://ipmsg.org/index.html.en

*IP Messenger for Win ver3.31 by H.Shirouzu

Answer (score 2):

Make sure it's in the list of "Allowed programs" in the Windows Firewall, and that it is enabled for both Private and Public access.  The Windows Firewall works differently in Windows 7 and essentially blocks all programs by default, and you have to go in and add exceptions for them.

Comment: Yes I did this but the problem still persists solved.

Comment: If you're operating behind a hardware firewall, then try temporarily disabling your Windows Firewall.  If the application works after that, then either there are some additional firewall settings needed, or the Windows Firewall is creating a compatibility problem.  If the application still doesn't work after that, then the vendor will likely have to fix it to work properly with Windows 7.

Comment: Their is some problem in win7 that this problem is causing when I am disconnected from internet at that time it shows my lan peoples and my lan ip address whereas when I go online it shows internet ip address and no lan peoples. This is the link of this software IPMSG http://ipmsg.org/index.html.en

Answer (score 0):

If IPMSG is working in Windows 7 as per your content, but after install Windows XP you getting troubles,
this is a compatibility problem.

To fix this problem Press "Properties", after click Program

[image]

Check your compatibility.